# Compare two Lists for differences

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-2.0

I would like some feedback on how we can best write a generic function that will enable two Lists to be compared. The Lists contain class objects and we would like to iterate through one list, looking for the same item in a second List and report any differences.

We already have a method to compare classes, so we need feedback on how we can feed the method (shown below) from two Lists.

For example, say we have a simple "Employee" class that has three properties, Name, ID, Department. We want to report the differences between List and another List.

Note:
Both lists will always contain the same number of items.

As mentioned above, we have a generic method that we use to compare two classes, how can we incorporate this method to cater for Lists, i.e. from another method, loop through the List and feed the classes to the generic method .... but how do we find the equivalent class in the second List to pass to the method below;

```
public static string CompareTwoClass_ReturnDifferences<T1, T2>(T1 Orig, T2 Dest)
    where T1 : class
    where T2 : class
{
    // Instantiate if necessary
    if (Dest == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Dest", "Destination class must first be instantiated.");

    var Differences = CoreFormat.StringNoCharacters;

    // Loop through each property in the destination  
    foreach (var DestProp in Dest.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        // Find the matching property in the Orig class and compare
        foreach (var OrigProp in Orig.GetType().GetProperties())
        {

            if (OrigProp.Name != DestProp.Name || OrigProp.PropertyType != DestProp.PropertyType) continue;
            if (OrigProp.GetValue(Orig, null).ToString() != DestProp.GetValue(Dest, null).ToString())
                Differences = Differences == CoreFormat.StringNoCharacters 
                    ? string.Format("{0}: {1} -> {2}", OrigProp.Name,
                                                       OrigProp.GetValue(Orig, null),
                                                       DestProp.GetValue(Dest, null)) 
                    : string.Format("{0} {1}{2}: {3} -> {4}", Differences,
                                                              Environment.NewLine,
                                                              OrigProp.Name,
                                                              OrigProp.GetValue(Orig, null),
                                                              DestProp.GetValue(Dest, null));
        }
    }
    return Differences;
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas appreciated?

Edit: Targeting .NET 2.0 so LINQ is out of the question.

Comment: lol ... no, a top level, system critical application :-)
seriously, trying to implement this functionality into a small hobby app ...its all learning.

Comment: Are the lists of equal length?

Comment: Equals ?? I am learning so happy to take this as a learning exercise. Can you expand?

Comment: Oops, I removed the comment. I meant equating the objects with the ID property. And adding a GetDiffereces() method for objects of equal ID.
And then using LINQ.

Comment: @pedro: LINQ *can* run on .NET 2.0. See http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> .... but how do we find the equivalent class in the second List to pass to the method
>   below;

This is your actual problem; you must have at least one immutable property, a id or something like that, to identify corresponding objects in both lists. If you do not have such a property you, cannot solve the problem without errors. You can just try to guess corresponding objects by searching for minimal or logical changes.

If you have such an property, the solution becomes really simple.

```
Enumerable.Join(
   listA, listB,
   a => a.Id, b => b.Id,
   (a, b) => CompareTwoClass_ReturnDifferences(a, b))
```

---

> thanks to you both danbruc and Noldorin for your feedback. both Lists will be the same
>   length and in the same order. so the method above is close, but can you modify this
>   method to pass the enum.Current to the method i posted above?

Now I am confused ... what is the problem with that? Why not just the following?

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < Math.Min(listA.Count, listB.Count); i++)
{
    yield return CompareTwoClass_ReturnDifferences(listA[i], listB[i]);
}
```

The Math.Min() call may even be left out if equal length is guaranted.

---

Noldorin's implementation is of course smarter because of the delegate and the use of enumerators instead of using ICollection.

Comment: sorry, we are targeting .NET 2.0. I should have made this point.

Answer (score 74):

This solution produces a result list, that contains all differences from both input lists. 
You can compare your objects by any property, in my example it is ID.
The only restriction is that the lists should be of the same type:

```
var DifferencesList = ListA.Where(x => !ListB.Any(x1 => x1.id == x.id))
            .Union(ListB.Where(x => !ListA.Any(x1 => x1.id == x.id)));
```

Comment: This is great. Communities really allow you to get another persons view on a problem. Thank you!

Comment: I believe this assumes that there are no duplicates in either list?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for a method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> CompareSequences<T1, T2, TResult>(IEnumerable<T1> seq1,
    IEnumerable<T2> seq2, Func<T1, T2, TResult> comparer)
{
    var enum1 = seq1.GetEnumerator();
    var enum2 = seq2.GetEnumerator();

    while (enum1.MoveNext() && enum2.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return comparer(enum1.Current, enum2.Current);
    }
}
```

It's untested, but it should do the job nonetheless. Note that what's particularly useful about this method is that it's full generic, i.e. it can take two sequences of arbitrary (and different) types and return objects of any type.

This solution of course assumes that you want to compare the nth item of `seq1` with the nth item in `seq2`. If you want to do match the elements in the two sequences based on a particular property/comparison, then you'll want to perform some sort of [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(relational_algebra)#Joins_and_join-like_operators) operation (as suggested by danbruc using `Enumerable.Join`. Do let me know if it neither of these approaches is quite what I'm after and maybe I can suggest something else.

**Edit:**
Here's an example of how you might use the `CompareSequences` method with the comparer function you originally posted.

```
// Prints out to the console all the results returned by the comparer function (CompareTwoClass_ReturnDifferences in this case).
var results = CompareSequences(list1, list2, CompareTwoClass_ReturnDifferences);
int index;    

foreach(var element in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:#000} {1}", index++, element.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This will walk both lists synchronously but the object might not be ordered in the same way in both lists.

Comment: Yes, of course. I couldn't quite gather from the question whether this was the case or not, but anyway I'd just edited the post before I read your comment, so it's now property qualified...

Comment: thanks to you both danbruc and Noldorin for your feedback.  
both Lists will be the same length and in the same order. so the method above is close, but can you modify this method to pass the enum.Current to the method i posted above?

Comment: No problem... The fact that both lists are of equal length and ordered identically does very much help matters, so I think this solution will do the job nicely (danbruc's is worth noting for a more general case).

Comment: (contd). Now, I'm not quite sure what you mean about passing enum.Current (the code above necessarily passes both enum1.Current and enum2.Current). I've edited the post to clarify how you might use the CompareSequences function.

Answer (score 2):

This approach from Microsoft works very well and provides the option to compare one list to another and switch them to get the difference in each. If you are comparing classes simply add your objects to two separate lists and then run the comparison.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I am understing your question correctly, but you can do this very quickly with Linq.  I'm assuming that universally you will always have an Id property.  Just create an interface to ensure this.

If how you identify an object to be the same changes from class to class, I would recommend passing in a delegate that returns true if the two objects have the same persistent id.

Here is how to do it in Linq:

```
List<Employee> listA = new List<Employee>();
        List<Employee> listB = new List<Employee>();

        listA.Add(new Employee() { Id = 1, Name = "Bill" });
        listA.Add(new Employee() { Id = 2, Name = "Ted" });

        listB.Add(new Employee() { Id = 1, Name = "Bill Sr." });
        listB.Add(new Employee() { Id = 3, Name = "Jim" });

        var identicalQuery = from employeeA in listA
                             join employeeB in listB on employeeA.Id equals employeeB.Id
                             select new { EmployeeA = employeeA, EmployeeB = employeeB };

        foreach (var queryResult in identicalQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(queryResult.EmployeeA.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(queryResult.EmployeeB.Name);
        }
```