# How to compare two  `List<MyObject1> with List<MyObject2>`?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

How to compare two  `List<MyObject1>` with `List<MyObject2>`?
So if one the Value has  different value it should be possible to check it.

(I know we can use `foreach`... But I'd like **LINQ** solution/)

Thank you!

```
public sealed class MyObject1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { set; get; }

    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}

public sealed class MyObject2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { set; get; }

    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to compare? The lists or the objects in the lists?

Comment: @ChrisF Let me correct my question pls... Done

Comment: Peretz enumerate through each object in List A and compare it to each object in List B.  Posting what you have attempted makes peoplel like myself more willing to give you a bigger hint.

Comment: there is a similar thread on this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675699/compare-two-lists-for-differences    it has few good linq expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class myComparer: IEqualityComparer  
{
   public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
   {
      if (x is string )
         return  x ==   y;
      else if (x is Guid ) // maybe you want them to be equal if last char is equal. so you can do it here.
         return   x ==   y;
      else
         return EqualityComparer<object>.Default.Equals(x, y);
   }

   public int GetHashCode(object obj)
   {
      return EqualityComparer<object>.Default.GetHashCode(obj);
   }
}
```

---

now

```
List<MyObject1 > lst1 = new MyObject1 <MyObject1 >(); 
//add items here...

List<MyObject2 > lst2 = new MyObject1 <MyObject2 >(); 
//add items here...
```

you can equate 2 ways :

```
IStructuralEquatable equ = lst1 ;

  Console.WriteLine(equ.Equals(lst2 , EqualityComparer<object>.Default));

   or

   Console.WriteLine(equ.Equals(lst2 , new myComparer()));
```

Comment: What do mean t1, t2 in your sample? Could you explain it please?

Comment: IMO, this is not a good solution. The type testing makes it expensive, and shoehorning everything to object so that you can use IEqualityComparer is too tricksy by half.

Comment: @spender as long they arent in inheritance mode - you dont have any option. if they'd have a inheritance relationship - we could do something which is type safe. but the OP didnt mentiond it. p.s. look at MSDN sample  - exactly as myne : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.istructuralequatable.aspx   they used TUPLES.

Comment: OK, fair enough. DV removed. Still doesn't look all that nice to me.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections-in-c) suggests using `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx).

The method takes two `IEnumerable`s and an `IEqualityComparer`. It iterates over both your enumerables in parallel and checks equality element by element using the comparer you provide.

In the IEqualityComparer implementation, you may want to compare MyObject instances by their Id properties.

If there really are two object types, you could do something like `MyList1.Select(new MyObject2 {/*mapping goes here*/})`or try using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: But IEqualityComparer is used for one type at the time

Comment: Updated my answer to deal with that.

Comment: I'm not fond of this solution, but +1 for introducing me to AutoMapper

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to (or can't) implement your own `IEqualityComparer`, you could zip and compare fields:

```
list1.Count == list2.Count 
&& list1
    .Zip(list2, (i1,i2) => new{i1,i2})
    .All(x =>    x.i1.Name  == x.i2.Name
              && x.i1.Value == x.i2.Value
              && x.i1.ID    == x.i2.ID)
```

Comment: the whole idea with ***rer is when you can't edit the class - so you use other class. your sentence is not logical `(or can't) implement your own IEqualityComparer`

Comment: How about `list1.Zip(list2, (i1, i2) => i1.Name = i2.Name && i1.Value == i2.Value && i1.ID == i2.ID).All()`?

Answer (score 2):

Your classes are the same, so I believe what you want to do is to compare two lists of Objects of type `MyObject`:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { set; get; }

    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

I find the easiest way to do this, without having to write a separate `IEqualityComparer`, is to have the `MyObject` class implement the `IComparable` interface.  This is explained in detail [halfway down this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx), but this is what your class would look like after implementing the interface:

```
public class MyObject :  IEquatable <MyObject >
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { set; get; }

    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MyObject other)
    {

    //Check whether the compared object is null. 
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

    //Check whether the compared object references the same data. 
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

    //Check whether the objects properties are equal. 
    return Name.Equals(other.Name) && Value.Equals(other.Value) && ID.Equals(other.ID);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

    //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
    int hashName = Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();

    //Get hash code for the Value field. 
    int hashCode = Value == null ? 0 : Value .GetHashCode();

    //Get hash code for the IDfield. 
    int hashID =  ID.GetHashCode();

    //Calculate the hash code for the entire object. 
    return hashName  ^ hashCode ^ hashId;
    }
}
```

Once your class has the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods, the LINQ `Except()` method will automatically work:

```
List<MyObject> objects1 = { new MyObject{ Name = "apple", Value= "fruit", ID= 9 }, 
                           new MyObject{ Name = "orange", Value= "fruit", ID= 4 },
                            new MyObject{ Name = "lemon", Value= "fruit", ID= 12 } };

List<MyObject> objects2 = { new MyObject { Name = "apple", Value= "fruit", ID= 9 } };

List<MyObject> comparison = objects1.Except(objects2);
```

`comparison` now has orange and lemon, but not apple. I like this solution because of how legible the code is in the last line.