# compare three arrays and show difference

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare two Lists for differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675699/compare-two-lists-for-differences)

I have following set of arrays

```
string[] arr1 = { 1155717, 5184305, 2531291, 1676341, 1916805 ... } 
string[] arr2 = { 1155717, 1440230, 2531291, 8178626, 1916805 ... }
string[] arr3 = { 1155717, 5184305, 4025514, 1676341, ... }
```

Arrays count is in millions & can contains characters as well.
I want to create a report like this in csv

```
diff.csv

arr1,arr2,arr3
1155717,1155717,1155717
5184305,--N/A--,5184305
--N/A--,1440230,--N/A--
--N/A--,--N/A--,4025514
1676341,--N/A--,1676341
--N/A--,8178626,--N/A--
1916805,1916805,--N/A--
```

I guess applying for loops in each & comparing wouldn't be that good approach.Any Ideas?

Few Things i missed :
1. Order doesnt matter.
2. Elements in a single list will be unique.
3. I plan to skip loops as far as possible & look for .NET 3.5 / 4.0 's new features in LINQ / Generics which I can apply here!

**For those voting negatively or closing this question please explain so?**

Comment: Sort them and loop through them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675699/compare-two-lists-for-differences

Comment: Have you tried the so-called naive approach of solving this with a series of nested loops yet?  If so, is performance unacceptable?

Comment: @GeorgesD : Its only for 2 Lists at a time I'm targetiing 3 list. Also its on .NET 2.0 I'm looking for .NET 3.5

Comment: In what order should the elements be in the final output? Or doesmn't it matter?

Comment: Sorry but what can be done for two can be done for 3 or more.

Comment: @nhahtdh I plan to use .NET 3.5 LINQ or any new feature other than loops.. loops is a straight forward approach

Comment: @Yuck As I said looping is straing forward approach which I'm aware looking for something different like any new features of .NET 3.5 /LINQ / Generics

Comment: @Pratik My close vote (not downvote) is because you haven't tried anything at all. LINQ methods are **very well documented** as well as covered on Stack Overflow. Show what you've tried so far; don't just arrive here today demanding solutions.

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't show any effort and/or isn't generally useful. Like GeorgesD points out, if you can compare 2, you can compare 3 or 4, or n lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq to GroupJoin:

```
string[] arr1 = { "1155717", "5184305", "2531291", "1676341", "1916805" };
string[] arr2 = { "1155717", "1440230", "2531291", "8178626", "1916805" };
string[] arr3 = { "1155717", "5184305", "4025514", "1676341" };

var allPossibleTerms = arr1.Union(arr2).Union(arr3);

allPossibleTerms
    .GroupJoin(arr1, all => all, a1 => a1, (all, a1) => new { Number = all, A1 = a1 })
    .SelectMany(joined => joined.A1.DefaultIfEmpty(), (collection, result) => new { collection.Number, A1 = result})
    .GroupJoin(arr2, joined => joined.Number, a2 => a2, (collection, a2) => new { Number = collection.Number, A1 = collection.A1, A2 = a2 })
    .SelectMany(joined => joined.A2.DefaultIfEmpty(), (collection, result) => new { collection.Number, A1 = collection.A1, A2 = result})
    .GroupJoin(arr3, joined => joined.Number, a3 => a3, (collection, a3) => new { Number = collection.Number, A1 = collection.A1, A2 = collection.A2, A3 = a3 })
    .SelectMany(joined => joined.A3.DefaultIfEmpty(), (collection, result) => new { collection.Number, A1 = collection.A1, A2 = collection.A2, A3 = result});;
```

Basically, this creates a master-list of all terms, and joins each array as it goes.

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Number   A1       A2       A3        ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1155717  1155717  1155717  1155717   ║
║ 5184305  5184305  -------  5184305   ║
║ 2531291  2531291  2531291  -------   ║
║ 1676341  1676341  -------  1676341   ║
║ 1916805  1916805  1916805  -------   ║
║ 1440230  -------  1440230  -------   ║
║ 8178626  -------  8178626  -------   ║
║ 4025514  -------  -------  4025514   ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done a small example with arrays of type int but this can be applied to strings

```
        int[] arr1 = { 1155717, 5184305, 2531291, 1676341, 1916805 } ;
        int[] arr2 = { 1155717, 1440230, 2531291, 8178626, 1916805 };
        int[] arr3 = { 1155717, 5184305, 4025514, 1676341 };

        foreach (int i in arr1)
        {
            Console.Write(i + "  ");
            foreach (int b in arr2)
            {
                if (i == b)
                    Console.Write(b + "  ");

            }
            foreach (int c in arr3)
            {
                if (i == c)
                    Console.Write(c + "  ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Only problem is that you are using loops within loops, so if your arrays are large then you performance will be effected. This is just a simple idea to get you thinking.

Comment: I would rather recommend using collections in this case and not normal arrays since collections have built in functions to help speed this type of process up.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this Linq query and `string.Join`:

```
string[][] all = new[] { arr1, arr2, arr3 };
int maxLength = all.Max(arr => arr.Length);
string separator = ",";
string defaultValue = "N/A";

var csvFields = all.Select(arr => Enumerable.Range(0, maxLength)
                   .Select(i => arr.Length <= i ? defaultValue : arr[i]));
string csv = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                        csvFields.Select(f => string.Join(separator, f)));
File.WriteAllText(path, csv);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/jZ4l52)

I put all arrays in a jagged array. Then i use an `int` range as starting point(0-4 in your sample since the largest array has 5 elements). Then i take 5 elements from each array and a default-value of `"N/A"` if the array is smaller than that index.

The last stage is to use `string.Join` to link all parts of each array with your separator (`","`) and every *line* with `Environment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this maxing out at O(4N) or something but maybe someone knows a faster method.

```
private void PrintDiff()
{
        public Dictionary<string, Model> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Model>();

        foreach (var entry in Array1)
        {
            dictionary.Add(entry, (new Model()).Add(entry, "Array1"));
        }
        foreach (var entry in Array2)
        {
            if (!dictionary.ContainsValue(entry))
                 dictionary.Add(entry, (new Model()).Add(entry, "Array2"));
        }
        foreach (var entry in Array3)
        {
            if (!dictionary.ContainsValue(entry))
                 dictionary.Add(entry, (new Model()).Add(entry, "Array3"));
        }


        //now print 
        foreach (var model in dictionary)
        {
            model.ToString();
        }
    }

public class Model
{

    public Model()
    {
        Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool ContainsEntry(string entry)
    {
        return Dictionary.ContainsValue(entry);
    }

    public void Add(string entry, string arrayName)
    {
        Dictionary.Add(arrayName, entry);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "FORMATED AS YOU WANT THEM";
    }
}
```