# Compare unique combination of Rows in 2 Datatable & find if they are same using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

> DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
>               DataTable odt = new DataTable();
>
> ```
>         odt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FILE_ID", typeof(string)));
>         odt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
>         oDs.Tables.Add(odt);
>         oDs.AcceptChanges();
>
>         for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
>         {
>             DataRow oDr = oDs.Tables[0].NewRow();
>             oDr["FILE_ID"] = "a" + i;
>             oDr["ID"] = "b" + i;
>             oDs.Tables[0].Rows.Add(oDr);
>         }
>         for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
>         {
>             DataRow oDr = oDs.Tables[0].NewRow();
>             oDr["FILE_ID"] = "c" + i;
>             oDr["ID"] = "d" + i;
>             oDs.Tables[0].Rows.Add(oDr);
>         }
>         oDs.AcceptChanges();
>
>         DataTable odt1 = new DataTable();
>
>         odt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FILE_ID", typeof(string)));
>         odt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
>         oDs.Tables.Add(odt1);
>         oDs.AcceptChanges();
>
>         for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
>         {
>             DataRow oDr = oDs.Tables[1].NewRow();
>             oDr["FILE_ID"] = "a" + i;
>             oDr["ID"] = "b" + i;
>             oDs.Tables[1].Rows.Add(oDr);
>         }
>         for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
>         {
>             DataRow oDr = oDs.Tables[1].NewRow();
>             oDr["FILE_ID"] = "c" + i;
>             oDr["ID"] = "d" + i;
>             oDs.Tables[1].Rows.Add(oDr);
>         }
>         oDs.AcceptChanges();
> ```

I need a LINQ query by which I can find if the combination of the values of rows (FILE_ID+ID) are unique & if they are the same in both the datatables

Comment: You have 2 tables. Each has multiple rows. So for a given table, you want to concatonate the row values (FILE_ID+ID) and compare that against the other rows of that table to determine if all results are unique? furthermore, you want to ensure both tables have the same content?

Comment: I don't want to concatenate the two rows but the combination of the values in a row must be unique and to ensure that both the table has the same row combination

Answer (score 0):

This gets you the non-unique values:

```
var notUnique = odt.AsEnumerable()
                            .GroupBy(x => (string) x["FILE_ID"] + x["ID"])
                            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Finding the values that are in one table but not the other is found here
[Compares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675699/compare-two-lists-for-differences)

Your particular case would look like this:

```
  var differentRows =
            odt.AsEnumerable().Where(
                o =>
                odt1.AsEnumerable().All(
                    o1 => ((string) o["FILE_ID"] + o["ID"]) != ((string) o1["FILE_ID"] + o1["ID"])))
                .Union(odt1.AsEnumerable().Where(
                o1 => odt.AsEnumerable().All(o => ((string)o["FILE_ID"] + o["ID"]) != ((string)o1["FILE_ID"] + o1["ID"]))));
```

Keep in mind this is like the "except" method where duplicate records wont present themselves as a difference.  But since you are checking for dupes above I will assume no further checking is req'd.

Comment: This query was right until there were no DBNull values in any columns. If by accidently any DBNULL.Value came in any DataTable there would be problems.